# How to represent\maintain a master detail relationship in a RESTful way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

Behind our ASP.net Web API we have a code first entity framework model. Consider the following (simplified) entities:

```
public class Form
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public virtual FormGroup Group { get; set; }
}

public class FormGroup
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Form> Forms { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there is a 1-Many relationship between FormGroups and Forms. My question is, how should one design a RESTful API that allows us to change which Group a Form belongs to?

I have so far come up with two potential approaches, with pros and cons for each:

**Represent the relationship as a link structure:**

```
{
    "Id" : 1,
    "Identifier" : "Form1",
    "link" : {
        "rel": "http://myapi/res/formgroup",
        "href": "http://myapi/formgroups/1"
    }
}
```

Pros:

- Includes a meaningful link to the formgroup representation

Cons:

- There is no particular standard for such links
- Server side logic becomes more complicated

**Use PUT to link resources together**

```
data: {
    "Id" : 1,
    "Identifier" : "Form1"
}

PUT data to http://myapi/formgroups/1/forms
```

Pros:

- No extraneous properties on representations

Cons:

- Resources can be identified by multiple URIs i.e /forms/1 and also /formgroups/1/forms/1
- Sending any data other than that required to form a key is either extraneous, or confusing

I am not particularly happy with either of these approaches as they each seem to have more drawbacks than positives.

I know that a 'proper' solution would be to implement DTOs and seperate my entity model from my resource representation, which would allow me to add say a FormGroupId which I can set.

Like all good programmers however I am curious to see how this is intended to work in a RESTful API. I would also like a solution that I can apply generically to any navigation properties in my model.

Answers on a postcard... Are either of these approaches valid or is there another way of doing things that I have missed?

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building your API based on a data model will only restrict your overall design. I tend to work *back* from my representations.

With complete control over your representations you can express relationships however you wish. For example, you may decide to include a representation of your `FormGroup` within your `Form` representation:

```
GET /api/forms/1

    {
      "Id" : 1,
      "Name" : "Form 1",
      "FormGroup" : {
        "Id" : 1,
        "Name" : "Form Group 1"
      }
    }
```

Or include the Forms in the `FormGroup` representation:

```
GET /api/formgroups/1

    {
      "Id" : 1,
      "Name" : "Form Group 1",
      "Forms" : [
        {
          "Id" : 1,
          "Name" : "Form 1"
        },
        {
          "Id" : 2,
          "Name" : "Form 2"
        }
      ]
    }
```

In fact you could do both. Just ensure that each resource only has a single URI identifier.

If you really want to embrace REST and include hypermedia links in your API responses I recommend you check out [Hypertext Application Lanaguage](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) (HAL). HAL provides a convention for expressing related links between resources. For example:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : { "href" : "/api/forms/1" },
    "related" : { "href" : "/api/formgroups/1" }
  }
  "Id" : 1,
  "Name" : "Form 1",
  "FormGroupId" : 1
}
```

Hopefully you can see that how you represent your resources does not determine how you **manage** the relationships between them.

How you do this should largely depend on what is logical in your scenario and can often be helped by deciding who *owns* the relationship.

Take the typical `Blog Post .* Comments` example. Comments make little sense by themselves. If I was to design an API for managing blog comments I'd likely do it like so:

```
POST   /posts/1/comments  - Add a comment to post 1
DELETE /posts/1/comments/1 - Remove comment 1 from post 1
```

Note that the comment does have identity, but only within the context of the blog post.

In your case (based on our discussions on twitter) you said that `Forms` do have identity outside of a `FormGroup`. You also said that you can have orphan forms - those that do not belong to a group.

With this in mind, it would make sense that you manage the `FormGroup` relationship via the `Form` resource. The simplest way would be to just set/update a `FormGroupId` property when you perform a POST or PUT to the forms resource. If (again this depends on your scenario), you require the ability to change the `FormGroup` without updating any other properties on a `Form` resource you may wish to send a PATCH or create a "sub-resource" for managing the relationship:

```
POST /api/forms/1/group -- set the form group for forms/1
{
  "formGroupId" : 10
}

DELETE /api/forms/1/group -- unlink forms/1 from its group
```

Unfortunately there is no "right way" to represent relationships between your resources. My advice is to just go with what feels the most natural.

Comment: Thanks for the insights... I am marking this as the answer because as you say, it is clear now that there is no right answer to this. Maybe we can set some kind of precedent with a good solution however :)

Comment: This is a while back, but it still pops up on google, so i will add just a little to it: In case you want to embrace REST further and want links you should have a look at [oData](http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/) (it's even been included in VS-Controllers in the meantime) so the coding you have to do is considerably less.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Currently the world of resources on ASP.NET Web API is mixed one where you define your routes somewhere while you have to managed resource relationship and link somewhere else. You can do hierarchical routing by defining each route on its own which has maintenance and performance implications.

I am thinking of bringing these together. Watch the space :)

---

Now in terms of response to your question, I would go with this:

```
/api/formgroups/1
/api/formgroups/1/forms/123
```

Maintaining links and setting up routes will still be more or less ad-hoc - for now.

Comment: if you would work with: /api/formgroups/1/forms/123 , how would your controller look like then? it's like u have one controller inside the other? api/{controller}/{id}/{controller}/{id}... I have no clue how i can create that kind of links, could you give me some advice / links ? thanks in advance